# Is there a way in graphQL to rename the keyword value so it is different when I access it

Tags: javascript, graphql

Is it possible to rename `content` to `text` in the sanityTestimonials graphql query so when I grab the value later it grabs the same data but has a different key value.

```
 query={graphql`
    query ReviewsQuery {
      sanityTestimonials {
        subTitle
        title
        testimonial {
          content //(rename this to text)
          email
          show
          name
          _key
        }
      }
    }
  `}
```

so I could later do this

```
  console.log(data.sanityTestimonials.text) (instead of .content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL supports [field aliases](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Field-Alias), which allow you to change the name of the field as it appears in the response from the server:

```
query ReviewsQuery {
  sanityTestimonials {
    subTitle
    title
    testimonial {
      text: content
      email
      show
      name
      _key
    }
  }
}
```